# How to get a normal distribution within a range in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, random, machine-learning, normal-distribution

In machine learning task. We should get a group of random w.r.t normal distribution with bound. We can get a normal distribution number with `np.random.normal()` but it does't offer any bound parameter. I want to know how to do that?

Comment: Shouldn't random samples of normally distributed data by definition be unbounded?

Comment: @Tom In some cases, bounding it is useful. For instance, if I want to jitter the center location for an image crop, but also ensure that it stays within the source image's pixel dimensions

Answer (score 81):

The **parametrization of `truncnorm` is complicated**, so here is a function that translates the parametrization to something more intuitive:

```
from scipy.stats import truncnorm

def get_truncated_normal(mean=0, sd=1, low=0, upp=10):
    return truncnorm(
        (low - mean) / sd, (upp - mean) / sd, loc=mean, scale=sd)
```

---

---

## How to use it?

1. Instance the generator with the parameters: *mean*, *standard deviation*, and *truncation range*:

   ```
   >>> X = get_truncated_normal(mean=8, sd=2, low=1, upp=10)
   ```
2. Then, you can use X to generate a value:

   ```
   >>> X.rvs()
   6.0491227353928894
   ```
3. Or, a numpy array with N generated values:

   ```
   >>> X.rvs(10)
   array([ 7.70231607,  6.7005871 ,  7.15203887,  6.06768994,  7.25153472,
           5.41384242,  7.75200702,  5.5725888 ,  7.38512757,  7.47567455])
   ```

---

## A Visual Example

Here is the plot of three different truncated normal distributions:

```
X1 = get_truncated_normal(mean=2, sd=1, low=1, upp=10)
X2 = get_truncated_normal(mean=5.5, sd=1, low=1, upp=10)
X3 = get_truncated_normal(mean=8, sd=1, low=1, upp=10)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True)
ax[0].hist(X1.rvs(10000), normed=True)
ax[1].hist(X2.rvs(10000), normed=True)
ax[2].hist(X3.rvs(10000), normed=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: +1. It's worth noting, though, that the function gets much quicker if `get_truncated_normal.rvs( )` is used immediately inside the function, instead of calling it outside. Of course, this helps only if you want random draws

Comment: This does not work properly 100% of the time. Using low=0, upp=1, it will sometimes give you negative numbers.

Answer (score 20):

If you're looking for the [Truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution), SciPy has a function for it called [`truncnorm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html)

> The standard form of this distribution is a standard normal truncated
>   to the range [a, b] — notice that a and b are defined over the domain
>   of the standard normal. To convert clip values for a specific mean and
>   standard deviation, use:
>
> a, b = (myclip_a - my_mean) / my_std, (myclip_b - my_mean) / my_std
>
> truncnorm takes a and b as shape parameters.

```
>>> from scipy.stats import truncnorm
>>> truncnorm(a=-2/3., b=2/3., scale=3).rvs(size=10)
array([-1.83136675,  0.77599978, -0.01276925,  1.87043384,  1.25024188,
        0.59336279, -0.39343176,  1.9449987 , -1.97674358, -0.31944247])
```

The above example is bounded by -2 and 2 and returns 10 random variates (using the `.rvs()` method)

```
>>> min(truncnorm(a=-2/3., b=2/3., scale=3).rvs(size=10000))
-1.9996074381484044
>>> max(truncnorm(a=-2/3., b=2/3., scale=3).rvs(size=10000))
1.9998486576228549
```

Here's a histogram plot for -6, 6:

[image]

Comment: Why you don't use  truncnorm(a=-2, b=2, scale=1)

Comment: Just to make it clear that a and b are shape parameters otherwise a reader might try -2, 2 with a scale different than 1, and then get random values outside [-2, 2]

Answer (score 1):

Besides @bakkal suggestion (+1) you might also want to take a look into [Vincent Mazet](http://miv.u-strasbg.fr/mazet/rtnorm/) recipe for achieving this, rewritten as [py-rtnorm](https://github.com/classner/py-rtnorm) module by [Christoph Lassner](http://www.christophlassner.de/blog/2013/08/12/Generation-of-Truncated-Gaussian-Samples/).

Answer (score 0):

You can subdivide your targeted range (by convention) to equal partitions and then calculate the integration of each and all area, then call uniform method on each partition according to the surface.
It's implemented in python:

`quad_vec(eval('scipy.stats.norm.pdf'), 1, 4,points=[0.5,2.5,3,4],full_output=True)`