# How to get a sample of normally distributed values from 0 to 1 using NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I would like to get a sample of normally distributed values from 0 to 1 using NumPy. I use `np.random.normal(mean, sigma, n)` for that, where `mean=0, sigma=0.1, n=100`. But most of values situated near 0.5. How to solve that and get values distributed from 0 to 1?

Comment: Normal distribution extends into both negative and positive infinity. What exactly do you mean by "normally distributed values *from 0 to 1*"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894191/how-to-get-a-normal-distribution-within-a-range-in-numpy

Comment: It's also not clear what you mean by "most of values situated near 0.5" (for a distribution with `mean=0`).