# How to generate sample data that forms a normal distribution between two bounds in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, normal-distribution

I'm looking to use Python to generate some sample data.

I'd like to build a function which takes an upper bound, lower bound, and size parameters. It would then return a list of the provided size that contains floats between the upper and lower bound that form a normal distribution.

```
def generate_normal_dist_samples(lower_bound, upper_bound, size):
    # Generate the data here
```

Can this be done using numpy.random.normal?

An example is to generate employee salary test data. If we know the lower_bound is 50K, and the upper_bound is 500K, how can I generate sample salaries that are between these two, but when summarized form a normal distribution?

Comment: Correct answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894191/how-to-get-a-normal-distribution-within-a-range-in-numpy#answer-44308018

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers are correct, suggesting to use truncnorm, but since the question specifically asks about numpy.random.normal, I will naively answer it as such with this hackish approach.

Note that the problem is somewhat ill stated as it does not specify the standard deviation of the normal distribution.

```
def generate_normal_dist_samples(lower_bound, upper_bound, size, scale=None):
   loc = (lower_bound + upper_bound)/2
   if scale is None:
      scale = (upper_bound-lower_bound)/2
   results = []
   while len(results) < size:
     samples = numpy.random.normal(loc=loc, scale=scale, size=size-len(results))
     results += [sample for sample in samples if lower_bound <= sample <= upper_bound]
   return results
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a truncated normal distribution, which you can find in the scipy package. 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html

```
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
r = truncnorm.rvs(a, b, size=1000)
```

where `a` and `b` are the boundaries.

Comment: without specifying the mean this will grab the tail of the sample between a and b which is unlikely to be what original post was looking for.

Comment: @Techniquab So what is the right solution? truncnorm doesn't take a mean.

Comment: @rjurney I think this would come closest to what the original post was about   r = truncnorm.rvs(-(a+b)/2, (a+b)/2, size=1000) +(a+b)/2

Comment: A clean and correct answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894191/how-to-get-a-normal-distribution-within-a-range-in-numpy#answer-44308018