# Numpy normal distribution within a range without standart deviation value

Tags: python, numpy, random, statistics, normal-distribution

I have to generate random values from an interval for a machine learning task. I want to have a normal distribution within a range in numpy and I searched on web for it. I found this question [How to get a normal distribution within a range in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894191/how-to-get-a-normal-distribution-within-a-range-in-numpy) but I don't have any column for standart deviation.

The values are like this :

```
−21.8 ± 6.7
−4.3 ± 0.1
−7.4 ± 0.5
```

So I know minimum value and maximum value. But there is nothing about standart deviation.

Thanks.

Edit:

I want to generate 10 values from these values. The first value is the mean. Second value show the distance between max (and the min) value and mean. To be clear:

[image]

x = -21.8

The minimum value of the graph will be -21.8 - 6.7 = -29.5

The maximum value of the graph will be -21.8 + 6.7 = -15.1

Comment: The normal distribution is unbounded, so I'm not sure what you want - I'm guessing the second value you have _is_ the standard deviation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. -21.8 is the base value and I want to generate 10 values between -29.5 (-21.8 - 6.7) and -15.1 (-21.8+6.7) so there is an interval. These values have to be in form of gaussian. @miradulo

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming and it is based upon a fundamental misunderstanding of a statistical concept

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks for your answer. It helps so much.

Comment: It is just a comment generated automatically when voting for this specific reason. Happy it was helpful - you are very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [scipy.stats.truncnorm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html) to draw a number of samples from a random normal variable. However there is the need to specify the variable mean and standard deviation as for any normal random variable. I understand that you don't know the std, yet it impacts greatly how data are generated. Let's see few examples going from one extreme to another:

```py
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
import seaborn as sns

m = -21.8
w = 6.7

for s in [0.5, 2, 7]:
   lower, upper = -w/s, w/s
   r = truncnorm(a=lower, b=upper, loc=m, scale=s)

   size = 1_000
   sample = r.rvs(size)
   sns.distplot(sample)
```

Which results in:

[image]

You can see that for `s=7` the distribution is almost flat and uniform, on the other hand for `s=0.5` it is extremely unlikely to be outside the range - you need to be 13-14 standard deviations from the mean.

Comment: s is not the standart deviation. It gives the max and min value. M+S and M-S are the min and max values.

Comment: I understand that, yet to sample from a normal random variable you need to specify the mean and std. I will edit my answer to see how different std value will greatly impact what you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can get mu and std from your data this way (you must supply all data not only min and max):

```py
from scipy.stats import norm

data=np.array([1,2,3,4])
mu, std = norm.fit(data)
```

Comment: In every line, I've another data. So I only have -21.8 and 6.7 as a first line, I want to create a gaussian between -15.1 and -28.5.

Answer (score -1):

from [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html)

```
import numpy as np

mean = −21.8
std = 6.7
top = mean + std
bottom = mean - std

size = 5
a = np.random.normal(loc=mean, scale=std, size=size)

redraw_mask = ~(bottom < a < top)
while(0 < redraw_mask.size):
    a[redraw_mask] = np.random.normal(loc=mean, scale=std, size=redraw_mask.size)
```

out:

Comment: You can see that 3 out of 5 values exceed the OP request for the range [-28.5, -15.1].

Comment: @FBruzzesi OP did not ask for cropped values, but for standard deviation.

Comment: His comment is stating that he wants 10 values within such range, drawn from a normal distribution. As I said, 3 out of 5 are not within the range

Comment: 6.7 is not standart deviation.

Comment: @kukuro then you should be clearer in your question. How about a minimal reproducible input and output?