# How to generate random number in range of truncated normal distribution

Tags: go, random, normal-distribution

I need to generate a value in range of truncated normal distribution, for example, in python you could use [`scipy.stats.truncnorm()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html#scipy.stats.truncnorm) to make

```
def get_truncated_normal(mean=.0, sd=1., low=.0, upp=10.):
    return truncnorm((low - mean) / sd, (upp - mean) / sd, loc=mean, scale=sd)
```

how it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894191/how-to-get-a-normal-distribution-within-a-range-in-numpy)

Is there any package to make something in go or should I write the following function myself?

I tried following, how the [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#NormFloat64) says, but it makes number not in the needed range:

```
func GenerateTruncatedNormal(mean, sd uint64) float64 {
    return rand.NormFloat64() * (float64)(sd + mean)
}
```

```
GenerateTruncatedNormal(10, 5)
```

makes 16.61, -14.54, or even 32.8, but I expect a small chance of getting 15 due to `mean = 10` -> 10 + 5 = 15 is maximum value which we can get. What is wrong here?

Comment: You haven't used NormFloat64() correctly (it should be `rand.NormFloat64() * float64(sd) + float64(mean)`) but that's not a truncated normal distribution -- it's a normal distribution. I don't believe there's any package that provides that distribution so you'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Although it's not exactly clear that that's what you want -- your `GenerateTruncatedNormal` function doesn't have `low` and `upp` parameters like `get_truncated_normal` from python, so something seems off.

Comment: @PaulHankin, as the docs says `NormFloat64 returns a normally distributed float64 in the range [-math.MaxFloat64, +math.MaxFloat64] with standard normal distribution (mean = 0, stddev = 1) from the default Source. To produce a different normal distribution, callers can adjust the output using`, so I suppose the result of the func can be adjusted using those 2 params I pass in the function

Comment: @PaulHankin,`GenerateTruncatedNormal(5, 1)` makes smaller numbers, than with 10 and 5 passed

Comment: Sorry, you're replying to me but I'm not sure what response you would like. Perhaps you're saying that you think the docs are saying you can write `rand.NormFloat64() * a + b` to get a truncated normal distribution, but if so that's wrong -- you get a normal distribution with sd a and mean b.

Comment: @PaulHankin, you are right, I treated the docs wrong. Thanks for the reply :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieving this consists of

- generating a number `x` from the Normal distribution, with the desired parameters for mean and standard deviation,
- if it's outside the range [low..high], then throw it away and try again.

This respects the [Probability Density Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) of the Normal distribution, effectively cutting out the left and right tails.

```
func TruncatedNormal(mean, stdDev, low, high float64) float64 {
    if low >= high {
        panic("high must be greater than low")
    }

    for {
        x := rand.NormFloat64()*stdDev + mean
        if low <= x && x < high {
            return x
        }
        // fmt.Println("missed!", x)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OsqOUqQ4-hS)

If the [low..high] interval is very narrow, then it will take a bit more computation time, as more generated numbers will be thrown away. However, it still converges very fast in practice.

I checked the code above by plotting its results against and compare them to the results of [scipy's truncnorm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44308018/871134), and they do produce equivalent charts.

Comment: Now I realize that "if the [low..high] interval is very narrow", then the desired PDF looks like a straight line, which is maybe not a typical usage of a normal-based distribution.